# Set onclick listener on every Grid View list

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

**UPDATE: I already found the answer by myself, by using if conditions or switch case, thank you!**

I want to make onclick listener on every grid view list.

When i click on the list, it'll make an Intent to a class, but when i click on the other list, it'll make an Intent to another class, and the other lists too.

**FirstFragment.java**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    View myView;
    GridView gridView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView) myView.findViewById(R.id.operview);
        gridView.setAdapter(new FirstAdapter(myView.getContext())); // uses the view to get the context instead of getActivity().

        return myView;
    }

}
```

**FirstAdapter.java**

```
public class FirstAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public FirstAdapter(Context context)
    {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        items.add(new Item("Indosat", R.drawable.ic_indosat));
        items.add(new Item("Telkomsel ", R.drawable.ic_telkomsel));
        items.add(new Item("XL", R.drawable.ic_xl));
        items.add(new Item("Axis", R.drawable.ic_axis));
        items.add(new Item("Tri", R.drawable.ic_tri));
        items.add(new Item("Tri", R.drawable.ic_smartfren));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return items.get(i).drawableId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        View v = view;
        ImageView picture;
        TextView name;

        if(v == null)
        {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_layout_item, viewGroup, false);
            v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
            v.setTag(R.id.text, v.findViewById(R.id.text));
        }

        picture = (ImageView)v.getTag(R.id.picture);
        name = (TextView)v.getTag(R.id.text);

        Item item = (Item)getItem(i);

        picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
        name.setText(item.name);

        return v;
    }

    private class Item
    {
        final String name;
        final int drawableId;

        Item(String name, int drawableId)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.drawableId = drawableId;
        }
    }
}
```

**first_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/operview"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:numColumns="2" />


</FrameLayout>
```

**first_layout_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <com.blogspot.tigaenamdelapanmobile.SquareImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:background="#55000000"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

thank you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FIXED..

I added this code to my FirstFragment.java to make a onclick listener on every gridview item.

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                            long id) {

        if (position == 0) {
            Intent def = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaIndosat.class);
            startActivity(def);
        } else if (position == 1) {
            Intent abc = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaTelkomsel.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        } else if (position == 2) {
            Intent abc = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaXlAxis.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        } else if (position == 3) {
            Intent abc = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaXlAxis.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        } else if (position == 4) {
            Intent abc = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaTri.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        } else if (position == 5) {
            Intent abc = new Intent(getActivity(), PulsaSmartfren.class);
            startActivity(abc);
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: And I can also use switch statement! I find it funny seeing the old (—or younger, idk—) me asking this question. Well, everyone learns at first. Thank you!